# When I create a class based generator, why do I have to call the next?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm reading the book Python Tricks. In the chapter about generators, it gives the following example (with some changes)

```
class BoundedGenerator:
    def __init__(self, value, max_times):
        self.value = value
        self.max_times = max_times
        self.count = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.count < self.max_times:
            self.count += 1
            yield self.value
```

After that, I write a loop, instantiate the generator and print the value:

```
for x in BoundedGenerator('Hello world', 4):
    print(next(x))
```

Why do I have to call the `next(X)` inside the loop?

I (think) I understand that the `__iter__` function will be called in the loop line definition and the `__next__` will be called in each iteration, but I don't understand why I have to call the next again inside the loop. Is this not redundant?
If I don't call the `__next__` function, my loop will run forever.

Comment: This is not jow you use generators, generators exist to allow you to write *iterators* without the class-overhead. So, a generator function makes a great `__iter__` method for a iterable (or any method you want to return an iterator from), but it doesn't make sense as the `__next__` method of an iterator class, unless you want your *iterator* to return *other iterators*.

Comment: Quite frankly, this is a terrible and confusing example if it comes from that book, it muddies the water on generators, iterators, and iterable (three distinct albeit related concepts)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation and your time. Just to try to show the author's point, he starts with this kind of example but goes along and uses generator functions and generator expression and he gives the same opinion that I could achieve the same without this boilerplate code using one of the two other options (expressions or functions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `__next__` method *itself* is a generator function due to using `yield`. It must be a regular function that uses `return` instead.

```
def __next__(self):
    if self.count < self.max_times:
        self.count += 1
        return self.value   # return to provide one value on call
    raise StopIteration     # raise to end iteration
```

---

When iterating, python calls `iter.__next__` to receive the new value. If this is a generator function, the call merely returns a generator. This is the same behaviour as for any other generator function:

```
>>> def foo():
...    yield 1
...
>>> foo()
<generator object foo at 0x106134ca8>
```

This requires you to call `next` on the generator to actually get a value. Similarly, since you defined `BoundedGenerator.__next__` as a generator function, each iteration step provides only a new generator.

Using `return` instead of `yield` indeed returns the value, not a generator yielding said value. Additionally, you should `raise StopIteration` when done - this signals the end of the iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanation. That makes sense to me know.